# Selecting the highest value from a choice of multiple columns, many of which are NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

```
 ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8 diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13 age
1  123           1           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  54
2 5345           2           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  65
3  234           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  23
4  453           4           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  22
5 3656           5          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  33
6  345           1           4           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  77
```

I would like to create another column where the highest value of the "diagnosis" columns is selected per row. Ideally using base R

Desired outcome would be an additional column c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#Names
nvec <- which(grepl('diagnosis',names(df)))
#Var
df$c <- apply(df[,nvec],1,max,na.rm=T)

ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8
1  123           1           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
2 5345           2           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
3  234           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
4  453           4           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
5 3656           5          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
6  345           1           4           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA
  diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13 age c
1          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  54 3
2          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  65 3
3          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  23 3
4          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  22 4
5          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  33 5
6          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  77 4

#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 5345L, 234L, 453L, 3656L, 345L), 
    diagnosis_1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), diagnosis_2 = c(3L, 
    3L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L), diagnosis_3 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
    3L), diagnosis_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), diagnosis_5 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), diagnosis_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_8 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), diagnosis_10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_11 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), diagnosis_12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), diagnosis_13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), age = c(54L, 
    65L, 23L, 22L, 33L, 77L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmax` with `do.call` ( you need to provide arguments as a list):

```
df$c <- do.call(pmax, c(df[ ,c(-1,-ncol(df))], na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
> do.call(pmax, c(df[ ,c(-1,-ncol(df))], na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 3 3 3 4 5 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmax()` on your dataframe with `do.call()` with `na.rm = TRUE` specified. This should scale reasonably well for a large dataframe. Hope it helps!!

```
do.call(pmax, c(df[startsWith(names(df), "diagnosis")], na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 3 3 3 4 5 4
```

Or, if it is easier to read, you can create a wrapper:

```
pmax_na_true <- function(...) pmax(..., na.rm = TRUE)
do.call(pmax_na_true, df[startsWith(names(df), "diagnosis")])
[1] 3 3 3 4 5 4
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = " ID diagnosis_1 diagnosis_2 diagnosis_3 diagnosis_4 diagnosis_5 diagnosis_6 diagnosis_7 diagnosis_8 diagnosis_9 diagnosis_10 diagnosis_11 diagnosis_12 diagnosis_13 age
1  123           1           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  54
2 5345           2           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  65
3  234           3          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  23
4  453           4           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  22
5 3656           5          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  33
6  345           1           4           3           1          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  77")
```